# How to check if a drop down menu is expanded with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I'm automating test for a **mobile site** and I have issues with a select (containing a list of country).

The menu is that way :

```
<select id="depart" name="fromIsoCode" aria-controls="depart" aria-expanded="false">
  <option value="xx">yyFullName</option>
  <option value="yy">yyFullName</option>
</select>
```

**Important note :** When the menu is clicked and the list is "visible" for the user, the attribute **"aria-expanded"** turns to **"true"**

The test I'm supposed to do is to check that once we select a value, the list is no longer visible/displayed.

I used something along the following code for my test :

```
By element = By.cssSelector("select#depart[aria-expanded=\"true\"]")
assertFalse(driver.findElement(element).isDisplayed());
```

The problem is that even if the element is not present when reaching these lines, `isDisplayed()` return true

When in debug mode the element `select#depart[aria-expanded=\"true\"]` is NOT in the DOM of the page (but `select#depart[aria-expanded=\"false\"]` is)

The result of `isDisplayed()` is reverse from what I expect :
For `select#depart[aria-expanded=\"true\"]` it's suppose to be false (I don't have the element in the DOM, but it's true, for `select#depart[aria-expanded=\"false\"]` it's supposed to be true (it is in the DOM) but it is false...

My first guess was that it has something to do with the fact that we select something previously but it turns out that no, it fails even if the check is the first thing I do on the page.

Second guess is that it's either something specific to select element, and/or a problem with trying to use `select#depart[aria-expanded=\"true\"]` and `select#depart[aria-expanded=\"false\"]` as different elements, but I don't have other idea how to deal with it.

---

**The questions are :**

1. **How do I check if a select/drop down menu is expanded with selenium/java ?**
2. Why is it not working as expected ?

---

**Edit 1** 03/09/18

I tried to test "aria-expanded" value, it give the same result.
I see it as false in the DOM when it's supposed to be false, but selenium gets "true" when looking at it in debug.

**Edit 2** 03/09/18

**Debugging I notice the following : If I "inspect" my browser BEFORE "watching" my variable, the result I got in debug is OK...**

The debug is pausing -> I add a watch on "aria-expanded" it gives "true" (instead of the expected "false") -> I rigth click my browser/Inspect the page "aria-expanded" is "false" -> I add a second watch with same element or "refresh" the first one, I got the right value in "aria-expanded" ("false")...
Increasing the wait time does nothing... A few more bullets to try and I'll be back with more info

**Edit 3** 03/09/18

The problem wasn't about the state of the drop down menu. Both my way and theGuy do the work to "Check if a drop down menu is expanded" (Question 1)

Since this is the main question I'm accepting theGuy answer.

Concerning question 2 : It's probably a specific issue which deserve its own question, I managed to temporarily get around it by sending "tabulation key" in the select. It's an "In Case of Emergencie" fix, but I don't want to keep the whole question pending and I don't want to let people without at least a lead.

Comment: @theGuy I switched "backslash double quote" for "simple quote", same result :/ The backslashes are just there to escape the double quote in string :( I'll try other way to remove them but I'm not confident :/

Comment: You're basically trying to test if HTML SELECTs are working. Why? If you use the `Select` class, you can select any option you want but the SELECT doesn't open. I wouldn't worry about whether the SELECT opens or not, just test your scenario... select an option and validate that any expected actions happened and move on.

Comment: @JeffC I agree that it's pointless to test this, but 1) I've been asked to do it, if I have to say "I can't do it" I want it to be 100% true 2) Even if the test case designer let it go there is still something that is not right and it's still upsetting me, it's not really about the test anymore it's about why it doesn't work and how to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
By element = By.cssSelector("select#depart[aria-expanded='true']")
assertFalse(driver.findElement(element).isDisplayed());
```

Here is another solution you can try:

```
// wait here after you have selected a value so element state is changed and selenium gets updated state. Thread.sleep(); would seem to work best in this case.
String text= driver.findElement(By.id("depart")).getAttribute("aria-expanded");
Assert.assertTrue(text=="false","Dropdown is not expanded");
```

Comment: None of them work... It behave as if the element IS in the oposite state (not the one it's supposed to be, and clearly not the one I see. The result and my eyes don't agree...

Comment: can you check if there is any other element with same locator and you are getting result for that element instead of the one which you require

Comment: Also, I would add some wait time before checking the state of the element. check my updated solution.

Comment: I'm 100% sure there is not another element (there is another select but it has a different ID, no possible confusion), I have some wait time, I just didin't include it in the code sample to keep it clear/simple

Comment: Testing the attribute give the same result, it's supposed to be false, but passes when I test for "true", and failing whe I test for "false". I edit the question to add this.